# Value Array inside Associative Array creates key when pushed into parent array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, associative-array

I want to add keys to this WP_Query `$args` array. They have nested arrays and for post-format the `terms` has to have an value array without keys to work. However when adding a key it autocreates a key `'0' => 'value'`.

PHP:

```
$args = array(
 'hierarchical' => true, 
 'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
);

$post_formats_query = array(             
    'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array('post-format-'. $format_value);
);

$args['tax_query']=$post_formats_query; //this seems to create unwanted key
```

Var dump:

```
array (
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'posts_per_page' => '-1',
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'tax_query' => 
  array (
    'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => 
    array (
      0 => 'post-format-gallery', //I WANT TO REMOVE THIS KEY
    ),
  ),
  'category_name' => NULL,
)
```

Comment: Looks perfectly wanted to me... what do you want as a key instead?

Comment: I want: `'terms' => array ( 'post-format-gallery')` without the key (seems like the WP function needs just values inside this array)

Comment: That's what you have though, everything has a key, not specifying keys results in a numeric array. You have one item so you have just a key of zero. An array of just values IS a numeric array

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this $args variable

Comment: Sorry, I think I missunderstood where the problem is '^_^

Comment: Worth noting, using array() to create an array is old syntax. You'd be better off just using []

Comment: Ah ok. Well the problem was that I had one level of array to little, so `$args['tax_query']=$post_formats_query;` should be `$args['category_name']=array($post_formats_query);`

Could you show an example?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP wants an array with any keys -- which is impossible.

Comment: Do it, I missunderstood the problem